# Master Page Handling

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I try to create the UWP application with one of the master page that have a banner
the flow of work is like this

A[Master] <==> B[Use Master Banner] <==> C [Use Master Banner] <==> D [Without Banner]

In A I declare

```
<Frame Name="MyFrame"/>
```

And use this code to navigate

```
MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(B));
```

It's work fine and then in page I'm only use this code to make C gone well

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(C));
```

But in the last page D I want to get rid of that banner how do I can remove the frame out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach is quite strange. Just create the reusable part as a UserControl and put it in all the needed pages.